# Xamarin Forms - Remove Banding from ShadowView with Gradients

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, styles

[image: Zoomed Image with Banding (Horizontal Lines]
I have a shadowview in my application as above. I have tried to achieve it using LinearGradient as below.

```
<LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1"> 
      <GradientStop Color="#D7D7DA" Offset="0.05"/>      
      <GradientStop Color="#D7D7D9" Offset="0.1"/>       
      <GradientStop Color="#D8D8DA" Offset="0.40"/>       
      <GradientStop Color="#DBDBDD" Offset="0.45"/>       
      <GradientStop Color="#DDDDDF" Offset="0.50"/>       
      <GradientStop Color="#DFDFE1" Offset="0.55"/>       
      <GradientStop Color="#E0E0E2" Offset="0.60"/>       
      <GradientStop Color="#E4E4E6" Offset="0.65"/>       
      <GradientStop Color="#E6E6E8" Offset="0.70"/>       
      <GradientStop Color="#E9E9EB" Offset="0.75"/>       
      <GradientStop Color="#ECECEE" Offset="0.80"/>       
      <GradientStop Color="#EEEEF0" Offset="0.85"/>       
      <GradientStop Color="#F4F4F6" Offset="0.95"/>       
      <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1.0"/>    
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

Even after following the above approach of multiple gradients, still we can see some horizontal lines are appearing.

Any idea for smooth transition other than breaking the view style in more gradient?

I have applied the above (multiple gradient stop), banding reduced to some extent but still present. I want to achieve smooth transition from top to bottom without banding lines.

Comment: What does it look like if you remove almost all of the gradient stops? Keep first one "#D7D7DA", and "#F4F4F6" and "Transparent". Be sure to test on an actual device; the emulator scales its image to display, this might cause banding.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve - it is appearing similar. I guess my issue might be with BoxView. As suggested below by Jianwei Sun - MSFT, I am taking a frame and adding Gradient to that. Let me update how it looks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="forms.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <Frame BorderColor="Transparent" 
               HeightRequest="200" 
               WidthRequest="500">
            <Frame.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="#D7D7DA" Offset="0.05" />
                    <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1.0" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Frame.Background>
        </Frame>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

It works well. In addition, you can remove `BorderColor="Transparent"` to see the border of frame and add `BackgroundColor="Tan"` to see the effect of shadowview:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="forms.MainPage" 
             BackgroundColor="tan">
```

Comment: Is the above code meant for MAUI? I am changing in the StackLayout with Vertical Orientation and making the change..Let me update how it looks.

Comment: @subhamoy-burman It also works for forms. Sorry about that. I updated the code...

Comment: @subhamoy-burman May I know whether your issue has been solved or not? If not, please share it in here. We can work together to figure it out. For more info you can refer to this doc: [Xamarin.Forms Brushes: Linear gradients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/brushes/lineargradient).

Comment: Sorry for responding late

we did something like this to fix it out

                            <GradientStop Color="#D2D2D2" Offset="0.0" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#D8D8D8" Offset="0.02" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#D9D9D9" Offset="0.04" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#DADADA" Offset="0.06" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#DBDBDB" Offset="0.08" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#DCDCDC" Offset="0.10" />

........................

Extended it to further gradients.

Comment: I upvoted the answer, but it did not exactly solve my issue. The designer was stringent to make pixel to pixel map by doing 1200% zoom. So had to go that route.